# How to install/use a war file in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, war, ubuntu-16.04

I have a `war` file downloaded from `gerrit`. How to use it on Ubuntu 16.04?

**Addendum:**

- I have no idea what `tomcat` is or means...

Answer (score 0):

I think, this URL will help you~!

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/install-quick.html

Tomcat is Web Application Server.

[image]

Client send request. Apache(Web Server) simply receives a request.

Tomcat does internal work.

As a result, Apache is able to represent static data and Tomcat can represent dynamic data.